# First time jQuery fadeOut() executes is not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have the jQuery below, which basically makes a transition between two screens. However the first time the .fadeOut() executes on the first function, it does not apply the "slow", only after another function is executed that the transition happens smoothly.

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    $(".first").fadeOut("slow").removeClass("active");
    $(".second").fadeIn("fast").addClass("active");
});
$(".prev").click(function(){
    $(".second").fadeOut("slow").removeClass("active");
    $(".first").fadeIn("fast").addClass("active");
});
$(".close").click(function(){
    $(".onBoarding").css("display","none");
});
```

I tried to make it work with .delay(), but it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide the relevant html?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code for this?
Do you have a snippet of this?

Comment: Is that inside documet.ready? Maybe site is not loaded into DOM yet

Comment: Problem is not really clear. Provide  a **runnable** [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I don't have the html for testing but I think this would work)

`.delay` didn't work because `.removeClass` doesn't go through a queue, you need to wait for the animation to finish and then remove the class, you do this by passing a callback function to the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` methods.

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    $(".first").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $(".second").fadeIn("fast", function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
$(".prev").click(function(){
    $(".second").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $(".first").fadeIn("fast", function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
$(".close").click(function(){
    $(".onBoarding").css("display","none");
});
```

**EDIT:**

And because I like to guide people to what I think is the right path, I recommend you to read about [caching jQuery objects](https://pseudosavant.com/blog/2014/01/30/js-101-cache-your-selectors/). Below I leave you an example of using it in your code:

```
var $next = $(".next");
var $prev = $(".prev");

var $close = $(".close");
var $onBoarding = $(".onBoarding");

var $first = $(".first");
var $second = $(".second");

$next.click(function(){
    $first.fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $second.fadeIn("fast", function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
$prev.click(function(){
    $second.fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $first.fadeIn("fast", function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
$close.click(function(){
    $onBoarding.css("display","none");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want the hidden element to fade in after the first has completed? Question is not really clear

If so use the complete callback of first animation to execute the second

```
$(".next").click(function() {
  $(".first").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active")
    $(".second").fadeIn("fast").addClass("active");
  });
});
```